# Access JSX react variables in a button

Tags: reactjs

I have mapped a list of responses from my backend mongodb to my frontend. For each response, I have also added a button. I want to add an voteResponse function for my vote button. How can I continue to have access to my {response.respondee} and {response.response} in my voteResponse function?

```
{responses.map((response) => (
                <div
                  key={response._id}
                  className='py-8 px-12 mb-12 bg-gray-50 border-b border-gray-100 transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:-translate-y-2'
                >
                  <NextLink href={`/responses/${response.response}`} passHref>
                    <div>
                      <div className='inline-block text-gray-900 mb-4'></div>
                      <h3 className='text-lg leading-normal mb-2 font-semibold text-black'>
                        {response.response}
                      </h3>
                      <p className='text-gray-500'>
                        {response.respondee.slice(0, 5)}...
                        {response.respondee.slice(38)}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </NextLink>
                  <div>
                    <button
                      type='submit'
                      className='inline-flex justify-center mt-3 py-1 px-3 border border-transparent shadow text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-cyan-600 hover:bg-cyan-700 focus:outline-none'
                      onClick={voteResponse}
                    >
                      Vote
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by 2 ways. First is by making a separate component which is being rendered in map function and pass response in it through props then each component will have access to it's `response.response` and `response.respondee`.

```js
funtion Response({response}){
const voteResponse = () =>{
  console.log(response.response, response.respondee)
}
return(
     <div key={response._id} className='py-8 px-12 mb-12 bg-gray-50 border-b border-gray-100 transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:-translate-y-2'>
  <NextLink href={`/responses/${response.response}`} passHref>
    <div>
      <div className='inline-block text-gray-900 mb-4'></div>
      <h3 className='text-lg leading-normal mb-2 font-semibold text-black'>
        {response.response}
      </h3>
      <p className='text-gray-500'>
        {response.respondee.slice(0, 5)}... {response.respondee.slice(38)}
      </p>
    </div>
  </NextLink>
  <div>
    <button type='submit' className='inline-flex justify-center mt-3 py-1 px-3 border border-transparent shadow text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-cyan-600 hover:bg-cyan-700 focus:outline-none' onClick={voteResponse}>
                      Vote
                    </button>
  </div>
</div>
  )
}

//use it like this 
{responses.map((response) => (
  <Response response={response} key={response._id} />
))}
```

Second way to `pass the index in voteResponse function` and then through that index you can access the those variables like `responses[index].response` and `responses[index].respondee`.

```js
{responses.map((response, index) => (
<div key={response._id} className='py-8 px-12 mb-12 bg-gray-50 border-b border-gray-100 transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:-translate-y-2'>
  <NextLink href={`/responses/${response.response}`} passHref>
    <div>
      <div className='inline-block text-gray-900 mb-4'></div>
      <h3 className='text-lg leading-normal mb-2 font-semibold text-black'>
        {response.response}
      </h3>
      <p className='text-gray-500'>
        {response.respondee.slice(0, 5)}... {response.respondee.slice(38)}
      </p>
    </div>
  </NextLink>
  <div>
    <button type='submit' className='inline-flex justify-center mt-3 py-1 px-3 border border-transparent shadow text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-cyan-600 hover:bg-cyan-700 focus:outline-none' onClick={voteResponse}>
          Vote
     </button>
  </div>
</div>
))}
```

Comment: I did it via method 1 thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Pass value to *onClick* prop: `onClick={() => voteResponse(response)}` and use it as `parameter` of `voteResponse` function:

```
const voteResponse = (res) => {
 console.log("response.respondee is: ", res.respondee) //<=== response.respondee value is res.respondee value
 console.log("response.response is: ", res.response)
}

{responses.map((response) => (
                <div
                  key={response._id}
                  className='py-8 px-12 mb-12 bg-gray-50 border-b border-gray-100 transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:-translate-y-2'
                >
                  <NextLink href={`/responses/${response.response}`} passHref>
                    <div>
                      <div className='inline-block text-gray-900 mb-4'></div>
                      <h3 className='text-lg leading-normal mb-2 font-semibold text-black'>
                        {response.response}
                      </h3>
                      <p className='text-gray-500'>
                        {response.respondee.slice(0, 5)}...
                        {response.respondee.slice(38)}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </NextLink>
                  <div>
                    <button
                      type='submit'
                      className='inline-flex justify-center mt-3 py-1 px-3 border border-transparent shadow text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-cyan-600 hover:bg-cyan-700 focus:outline-none'
                      onClick={() => voteResponse(response)
                    >
                      Vote
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
```